# Webpack importing all files and exporting it as an array

Tags: node.js, webpack, graphql

So I'm working with Graphql and have been schema stitching and my index file looks awfully long. For a small example:

```
import userSchema from "./user";
import hobbiesSchema from "./hobbies";
import jobSchema from "./job";
import petSchema from "./pet";


const linkSchema = gql`
  scalar Date

  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }
  type Mutation {
    _: Boolean
  }
  type Subscription {
    _: Boolean
  }
`;

export default [
  linkSchema,
  userSchema,
  petSchema,
  jobSchema,
  hobbiesSchema,
];
```

This becomes outrageously long if I plan to add like 20 more schemas! I'd like a way to add all files in a directory and then being able to export them. So I've seen a lot of instances of the same answer doing this:

```
const context = require.context('.', true, /^\.\/(?!index\.js).*\.js$/, 'sync');

let schemas = {};
context.keys().forEach(module => {
  schemas[module] = context(module);
});
```

So I tried to put this in an array and export that as an array of all my schemas pushing each of the module in the array and exporting it at the bottom. I thought this would work but it doesn't and I'm wondering why? I get an error.

My schemas are defined and exported in the form of

```
export default gql`
  //schema stuff
`
```

I tried doing the same thing separately for resolvers because the index file looks almost exactly the same as the schema index file and I get the error "[Error: "default" defined in resolvers, but not in schema]"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, all I had to do was add .default to context(module)!

```
const context = require.context('.', true, /^\.\/(?!index\.js).*\.js$/, 'sync');
let resolvers = [];

context.keys().forEach(module => {
  resolvers.push(context(module).default)
});

export default resolvers
```